# Flutter Weak network detection

Tags: flutter, network-connection

I want to do network management in a project. I can catch wifi,mobile or not a connection. But I need to catch the situation where the internet is slow. How can ı detect weak network connection?

Comment: You can achieve this by using the [internet_speed_test](https://pub.dev/packages/internet_speed_test) package... Or, you can do it manually by sending a ping to a server and evaluate how long did it take to get a response. Hope that works!

Comment: Not exactly to help but ı will try this package